# Adding new nodes based on the number of existing nodes using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to modify the following xml using XSLT:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <response>
       <folder>
          <CRDATTIM>2012-08-31-08.26.11.805400</CRDATTIM>
          <RECORDCD>F</RECORDCD>
       </folder>
       <case>
          <CRDATTIM>2014-03-26-05.22.22.339840</CRDATTIM>
          <RECORDCD>C</RECORDCD>
          <issue>
             <KEY>2014-03-26-05.22.22.193840T01</KEY>
             <PRTY>999</PRTY>
          </issue>
       </case>
       <folder>
          <CRDATTIM>2012-11-06-23.57.08.089400</CRDATTIM>
          <RECORDCD>F</RECORDCD>
       </folder>
       <case>
          <CRDATTIM>2014-04-29-06.58.32.992840</CRDATTIM>
          <RECORDCD>C</RECORDCD>
          <issue>
             <KEY>2014-04-29-06.58.31.305840T01</KEY>
             <PRTY>999</PRTY>
          </issue>
       </case>
</response>
```

Now, I want to add a new node  `<sort>` to the root node `<response>` such that the node `<sort>` will contain two children  `<field />` and  `<ascending />` .But, here for each case in the above xml, the two tags  `<field />` and `<ascending />`  should be added to the `<sort>` node.For example in the above xml, there are two cases(`<case>`). So, the node `<sort>` should have two `<field />` tags and `<ascending />` tags. Ultimately, My final xml should look like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
   <folder>
      <CRDATTIM>2012-08-31-08.26.11.805400</CRDATTIM>
      <RECORDCD>F</RECORDCD>
   </folder>
   <case>
      <CRDATTIM>2014-03-26-05.22.22.339840</CRDATTIM>
      <RECORDCD>C</RECORDCD>
      <issue>
         <KEY>2014-03-26-05.22.22.193840T01</KEY>
         <PRTY>999</PRTY>
      </issue>
   </case>
   <folder>
      <CRDATTIM>2012-11-06-23.57.08.089400</CRDATTIM>
      <RECORDCD>F</RECORDCD>
   </folder>
   <case>
      <CRDATTIM>2014-04-29-06.58.32.992840</CRDATTIM>
      <RECORDCD>C</RECORDCD>
      <issue>
         <KEY>2014-04-29-06.58.31.305840T01</KEY>
         <PRTY>999</PRTY>
      </issue>
   </case>
   <sort>
      <field />
      <ascending />
      <field />
      <ascending />
      <field />
   </sort>
</response>
```

Please share your thoughts on how to achieve the desired functionality. Please let me know if my question is not clear. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an identity template to copy the original XML and put a `<sort>` element on the end. See next tutorial: http://www.xmlplease.com/xsltidentity

Here is an XSLT example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="response">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
            <sort>
                <xsl:for-each select="case">
                    <field />
                    <ascending />
                </xsl:for-each>
            </sort>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```